# How to get exact data after applying filter on data provider?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, hierarchical-data

I am having N-Level hierarchical data.
It is the data about Products inside N-Level of Product categories.

After applying filter on the data, I want only that much data which satisfies the filter condition because I need to display counts after applying filter.

But the problem is I am not able to get such data from anywhere.
I have found such data in **visibleData** property of AdvanceDataGrid, but there is no way to access that property as it is defined as protected.

Please reply me if you have any other solution for my problem.

Please find my code as below:

```
<common:MyAdvancedDataGrid id="productsDataGrid"
                            width="100%"
                            height="100%"
                            focusRect="null"
                            borderVisible="false"
                            horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
                            doubleClickEnabled="true"
                            selectionMode="multipleRows"
                            sortExpertMode="true"
                            draggableColumns="false"
                            defaultLeafIcon="{ null }"
                            displayItemsExpanded="true"
                            folderOpenIcon="{ null }"
                            folderClosedIcon="{ null }"
                            focusSkin="{ null }"
                            rowHeight="33"
                            sortableColumns="false"
                            variableRowHeight="true"
                            headerHeight="35"
                            resize="productsDataGrid_resizeHandler(event)"
                            keyDown="onProductDataGridKeyDown(event)"
                            creationComplete="onDataGridCreationComplete(event)"
                            selectedIndex="0">

                            <common:dataProvider>
                                <mx:HierarchicalData id="hierarchicalData"
                                                    source="{_hirarchyProductArr}"
                                                    childrenField="childCategory"/>
                            </common:dataProvider>
```

Filter Code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

private var _searchProductArr:Array;

private function onSearchChange1():void
{
    _searchProductArr = new Array();
    productsCount = 0;

    IHierarchicalCollectionView(productsDataGrid.dataProvider).filterFunction = browseFilter;

    // refresh the ADG's dataProvider
    IHierarchicalCollectionView(productsDataGrid.dataProvider).refresh();


}

//Filter Function
private function browseFilter(item:Object):Boolean
{
    if (item is Product)
    {
        var searchString:String = txtSearch.text;
        if (searchString.length == 0 || item.productName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
        {
            if (drdSelectProductType.selectedItem.label == ProductConstants.ALL_STR)
            {
                if(!isProductExist(item as Product))
                {
                    _searchProductArr.push(item);
                    productsCount = _searchProductArr.length;
                }

                return true;
            }
            else if (drdSelectProductType.selectedItem.label == ProductConstants.ACTIVE_STR && (item as Product).isActive)
            {
                if(!isProductExist(item as Product))
                {
                    _searchProductArr.push(item);
                    productsCount = _searchProductArr.length;
                }

                return true;
            }
            else if (drdSelectProductType.selectedItem.label == ProductConstants.INACTIVE_STR && !(item as Product).isActive)
            {
                if(!isProductExist(item as Product))
                {
                    _searchProductArr.push(item);
                    productsCount = _searchProductArr.length;
                }

                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var hasValidChildren:Boolean = false;
        for each(var node:Object in item.childCategory)
        {
            if (browseFilter(node))
            {
//                        productsCount = productsCount - 1;
                hasValidChildren = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return hasValidChildren;
    }
}

private function isProductExist(value:Product):Boolean
{
    for each(var product:Product in _searchProductArr)
    {
        if(product.productId == value.productId)
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
]]>
```

Comment: Post some code, there are many different ways a collection can be represented in code and filtered.

Comment: What does the dataProvider property give you after the filter function and refresh?

Comment: It is giving me the entire branch of the tree to which the records satisfying the filter condition belong. As it is giving entire branch with all records belonging to that branch tree. I don't want any data which doesn't satisfy the filter condition. DataProvider, HierarchicalData, Source etc are various properties giving me such entire branch with all its records.

Comment: sorry for not digging through your whole filter code, but are you trying to use the filter function to reduce the tree at other levels then the first one? I dont think that can work. If I misunderstood you, maybe you should add the minimal amount of input, expected output and recieved output.

Comment: No sir, I am not using the filter function to reduce the tree at other levels then the first one.. I have used it for normal filtering only. And it is filtering data and displaying the filter data in datagrid with 100% accuracy .. That isn't the issue..

Comment: As I have mentioned that I want the exact count of records which are displayed in datagrid after applying filter, I am nither able to get that exact count nor the records satisfying the filter condition from anywhere in datagrid or dataprovider's properties.. Instead of that in datagrid or dataprovider's properties I m getting the entire branch to which the filtered records belongs, along with those records too which does not satisfy the filter condition but belonging to same branch